# Reference Adobe Reader dll to control pdf?

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, dll, adobe

I am working on a Vb.net program in Visual Basic that takes a table of data from a pdf and puts it into an Excel doc. I want the program to work with Adobe reader so the user doesn't have to install Acrobat. I know there HAS to be a way to do this, and Adobe reader has a library called "AcroRd32" that I suspect would contain useful methods for doing this.

I think it would be illegal to decompile the library to see how the methods control the pdf, so that's out. I know there are libraries like itextsharp that will do it, but I want to find my own solution. So can I reference the Adobe Reader(not Acrobat) libraries and try to copy the table of data? Would this work? Or make my own library to control it?

I'm pretty much a beginner at .net so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I **strongly recommend** you use a WebBrowser control to display your PDF rather than embedding Adobe Reader.

However, to answer your question, you *must* install Adobe Reader on each PC to use it.

Then...

1. Right-Click the toolbox in the VB IDE and click "Choose Items"
2. Add reference to the "Adobe PDF Reader" COM component
3. Add the control to the form

NOTE: control does not work under 64-bit Windows.
To get around this, set Project Properties>Compile>Target CPU=x86

This will force the application to compile as a 32-bit application, which will then run on 64-bit windows under emulation ("WoW64")

When copying a form with a PDFReader control on it, you may need to add a new reader control to a form and then remove it for the VB IDE to add the reference correctly (Even if it is in the toolbox, Adobe Reader only gets added as a reference the first time you use it)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That helps a lot, although I wasn't referring to embedding, I just meant opening the Adobe shell in the background and copying the data that I need. I will try opening the PDF in web browser and parsing the data. Thanks

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. Copying data out of a PDF will be difficult without a third-party library like Aspose.